# How do I access a Perl object from the memory location?

Tags: ajax, perl, session, persistence

I want to access a Perl object in a script, which has been passed through Ajax.

I can't pass the object itself through JS Ajax, so I passed in the memory location for the object I want to access.

Now in the Perl script I have a memory location, for example

```
my $obj = "ClassName=HASH(0x9dccdb18)";
```

Now if I want to access the actual object for ClassName from this string of memory location, how can I do it?

I want to be able to access the object and run the subroutines on that object.

Comment: The process that had the object no longer exists, so even if a memory address into that process was useful at some point, it isn't anymore.

Comment: Why are you sending memory location in the first place? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/222077

Comment: The "X" in this problem is how to persist an object across separate calls to the back end.

Comment: s/how to persist \Kan object/data/. Two options: 1) pass the data to the browser, and have the browser send it in the following requests, or 2) store the data locally, pass a token to the browser that identifies the storage location, and have the browser send the token in the following requests.

Comment: What framework are you using on the backend? Different frameworks will accomplish this task in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Some of the reasons are spelled out in the comments. One additional reason is that even if you were to arrange to return the string to the same processes that generated it, there is no way you can be sure that the object still exists, or that if it does it still lives at the same memory location. The only purpose of that string is to give the object a unique name.

You probably need to read `perldoc Storable`. You definitely need to ask about the actual problem you're trying to solve rather than something you think may be a solution to it.